# How to enable app SideLoading feature in sharepoint 2013 foundation

Tags: 2013

How to enable app SideLoading feature in sharepoint 2013 foundation ?

I am getting path not found error when trying this,

```
$programFiles = [environment]::getfolderpath("programfiles")

add-type -Path $programFiles'\SharePoint Online Management Shell\' + `
  'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'

Write-Host `
  'To enable SharePoint app sideLoading, ' + `
  'enter Site Url, username and password'

$siteurl = Read-Host 'Site Url'
$username = Read-Host "User Name"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Password'

if ($siteurl -eq '') {
    $siteurl = 'https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite'
    $username = 'me@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com'
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'mypassword!'`
                -AsPlainText -Force
}
$outfilepath = $siteurl -replace ':', '_' -replace '/', '_'

try
{
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$cc = `
      New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials]$spocreds = `
      New-Object `
      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)

    $cc.Credentials = $spocreds
    $sideLoadingEnabled = `
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.appcatalog]::IsAppSideloadingEnabled($cc);

    $cc.ExecuteQuery()

    if($sideLoadingEnabled.value -eq $false) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow `
          'SideLoading feature is not enabled on the site:' $siteurl
        $site = $cc.Site;
            $sideLoadingGuid = `
           new-object System.Guid "AE3A1339-61F5-4f8f-81A7-ABD2DA956A7D"
            $site.Features.Add($sideLoadingGuid, $false, `
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None);
            $cc.ExecuteQuery();
           Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green `
          'SideLoading feature enabled on site' $siteurl
    }

    Else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green `
          'SideLoading feature is already enabled on site' $siteurl
    }
}

Catch { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red `
      'Error encountered when trying to enable SideLoading feature' `
      $siteurl, ':' $Error[0].ToString();
}
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/12/10/enable-app-sideloading-in-your-non-developer-site-collection.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable side loading by activating the hidden Developer feature.

For that open up PowerShell and execute

```
Enable-SPFeature e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085 –url http://siteurl
```